# Undefined method 'remember_token=" while following railsturial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have seen several questions regarding this issue bot none of them helped me. So the problem is, while executing if I check remember me I get this error:

"undefined method `remember_token=' for #"

relevant code:

User.rb

```
#Returns a random token.
def User.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
# Rememember a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
 def remember 
   self.remember_token = User.new_token **# This is the row 30 where the execution stops**
   update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
```

I have checked the database has got the column remember_digest so it's not the database column.

This code is being called from session_helper.rb i.e. from code:

```
# Remembers a user in a persistent session.
def remember(user)
  user.remember 
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  cookies.permament.signed[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

Also in my console if I type User.new_token the console return new token without a problem.

Comment: Is `**# This is the row 30 where the execution stops**` actually in your codes? If that's supposed to be a comment, I think the `**` shouldn't be there.

Comment: No it's not in the code it's a comment I added in stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: "undefined method `remember_token='

You are getting this error because users table doesn't have a remember_token field.

> I have checked the database has got the column remember_digest so it's not the database column.

***When you use `self.remember_token = User.new_token`, you are trying to set remember_token field in users table with output of new_token method.*** Why do you think you need to have remember_digest field in users table when you are assigning it to remember_token?

**FIX**

If you want to implement remember me functionality then you can follow this [`railscast`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password). Your code would be something like this:

```
#User.rb
#Returns a random token.
def new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
# Rememember a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
def remember
  self.update_attribute(:remember_digest, new_token)
end

# Remembers a user in a persistent session.
def remember(user)
  user.remember 
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_digest
  cookies.permament.signed[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

P.S I'm using remember_digest as it's already in your users table. You can change it and use a more descriptive field like remember_token

Comment: what is the difference between 'def new_token' and 'def User.new_token' ?

Comment: @adnanPirota User.new_token or self.new_token are class methods and new_token is a instance method, called on instance variables

Answer (score 1):

I too was stuck with this problem while practising the rails tutorial book.

The mistake I did was that I forgot to write 
`attr_accessor :remember_token`
which was the reason for the variable not being accessed by the `remember(user)` method.

I was also frustrated with this problem but luckily I found the solution.

**PS: Check If you wrote `attr_accessor :remember_token` in the User model's class (user.rb)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was struggling with this problem and in the end I found Naga Sudhir's answer solved the issue.

It turns out I didn't understand that `attr_accessor :remember_token` was actually a line of code I had to enter in the User models class (user.rb).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25}
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  has_secure_password
```

That allows `self.remember_token` to be used later in the code.

Hope that clears it up and helps anyone else struggling through the tutorial. :)